PSP homebrew compiled with custom build system crashes in startup code
I'm working on porting my game engine to the PSP using the open source pspdev toolchain. It builds, but when I run it in an emulator or on real hardware, it crashes. In the emulator, I've been able to trace it to system calls made in crt0 and libc being the cause of the crashes. I don't know what I'm doing differently from the official Makefile, if anything.
This is as much of the startup code as I think is relevant to the problem:
PSP_MODULE_INFO(PURPL_EXECUTABLE_NAME, 0, 1, 0);
PSP_MAIN_THREAD_ATTR(THREAD_ATTR_VFPU | THREAD_ATTR_USER);

unsigned int sce_newlib_nocreate_thread_in_start = 1;
const char *sce_newlib_main_thread_name = "main";

INT main(INT argc, PCHAR *argv)
{
    return 0;
}

It crashes in external code (either _start or __libcglue_init before reaching main, either from calling sceKernelCreateThread or sceKernelCreateLwMutex, depending on if sce_newlib_nocreate_thread_in_start is defined.
Here's my build flags:
local pspdev = os.getenv("PSPDEV")

toolchain("psp")
    set_kind("standalone")

    set_sdkdir(pspdev)
    set_bindir(path.join(pspdev, "bin"))

    set_toolset("cc", "psp-gcc")
    set_toolset("cxx", "psp-g++")
    set_toolset("ld", "psp-g++")
    set_toolset("sh", "psp-gcc")
    set_toolset("ar", "psp-ar")
    set_toolset("as", "psp-gcc")

    on_load(function (toolchain)
        toolchain:add("cxflags", "-D__unix__")
        toolchain:add("cxflags", "-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE")
        toolchain:add("cxflags", "-D__INT32_TYPE__=int")
        toolchain:add("cxflags", "-D__UINT32_TYPE__=unsigned")
        toolchain:add("ldflags", "-Wl,-zmax-page-size=128")

        for _, includedir in ipairs({
            path.join(pspdev, "include"),
            path.join(pspdev, "psp", "include"),
            path.join(pspdev, "psp", "sdk", "include")
        }) do
            toolchain:add("cxflags", "-I" .. includedir)
        end

        for _, libdir in ipairs({
            path.join(pspdev, "lib"),
            path.join(pspdev, "psp", "lib"),
            path.join(pspdev, "psp", "sdk", "lib")
        }) do
            toolchain:add("ldflags", "-L" .. libdir)
        end

        for _, lib in ipairs({
            "atomic",
            "pspge",
            "pspdisplay",
            "pspvfpu"
        }) do
            toolchain:add("ldflags", "-l" .. lib)
        end
    end)
toolchain_end()


You need to narrow it down to a minimal example and post the code here on this site.
